Gauss map and connections
In differential geometry of surfaces, I learnt that the Weingarten map( or shape operator) a hypersurface $f:M^n\to\mathbb R^{n+1}$ is defined as the differential $N_*$ of the Gauss map $N:M\to S^2$ up to a sign, and second fundamental form is $$B(X,Y)=g(N_*X,Y)$$. In Riemannian geometry, the second fundamental form is defined by $$B(X,Y)=\hat \nabla_X(Y)-\nabla_X Y=g(\hat \nabla_X(Y)-\nabla_X Y,n)n=g(\hat \nabla_X(Y),n)n=-g(\hat\nabla_X n,Y)n$$(here $\hat\nabla$ is connection in ambient space) where $n$ is local unit normal vector field on $M$, and Weigarten map is just $X\mapsto \nabla_X n$. One can show that they are same by local coordinates, but I am looking for a coordinate free proof.
Basicly, $N$ is just $n:M\to T^{\perp}M$ composed with the identification $T^{\perp}M\to T\mathbb R^{n+1}\to \mathbb S^n$ which involves identifications $T\mathbb R^{n+1}=\mathbb R^{n+1}\times \mathbb R^{n+1}$, and $N_*X$ is again identified as a vector in $TM$.
Starting from here, how does one handle various identifications and show that $N_*X=\nabla_X n$ without using the language of coordinates? Is this a general result for ambients space with trivial tangent bundle? Namely, if we have a hypersurface $M^n\to N^{n+1}$ with $\pi:TN=N\times \mathbb R^{n+1}\to \mathbb R^{n+1}$ and the metric of $M$ is pullback from $N$, then $N=\pi \circ n$, can we identify $N_*X=(\pi\circ n)_*X$ with $\nabla_X n$?

All that's going on here, I believe, is that for and vector-valued function $g$ on $M$, vector field $X$ on $M$, and $p\in M$, we have $dg_p(X_p) = X_p(g) = (\nabla_X g)(p)$.
